# Print digital to string in C language

Tags: c, string, macros, enums, digital

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define stringify(s)    tostring(s)
#define tostring(s)     #s

#define MAX_VALUE 65536
#define NUM 64 * 1024

enum {
    MIN_VALUE = 1024,
};

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    const char *max_str = stringify(MAX_VALUE);
    const char *min_str = stringify(MIN_VALUE);
    printf("max = %s, min = %s\n", max_str, min_str);
    return 0;
}
```

The output is "max = 65536, min = MIN_VALUE num = 1024 * 64"
Experts, how can I modify my code to output like this:
max = 65536, min = 1024 num = 65536

Thanks .

Comment: MIN_VALUE is `enum` constant, don't macro. Preprocessor know nothing about it.

Comment: `const char min_str[10]; snprintf(min_str, 9, "%d", MIN_VALUE);`

Answer (score 3):

MIN_VALUE is a number. Why do you need to stringify it?

Just use:

```
printf("%d\n", MIN_VALUE);
```

Comment: I have to pass a string to a function, but I have no the function permission to modify the function. So...

Comment: than prepare a string where you need it instead of stringifying at compile time

Answer (score 0):

I think you're better off using a function instead of a macro for this, the reason being that macros are only expanded even before compile time, let alone runtime.

consider this example:

```
#define stringify(V) #V

#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int x = 5;
    const char *str = stringify(x);
    printf("%s\n", str);
}
```

after the preprocessor has done it's work, the code will look like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int x = 5;
    const char *str = "x";
    printf("%s\n", str);
}
```

that is because all the preprocessor directive `#` does, is wrap the given parameter in quotes.

If you want to have an int to string behaviour that works on constants, enums (cast to int) and integer variables, you could use `sprintf`:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

char *stringify(int x)
{
    /* get the length of the required buffer */
    int len = snprintf(0, 0, "%i", x);
    /* allocate memory */
    char *res = malloc(sizeof(char) * (len + 1));
    /* handle allocation failure */
    if(!res)
        return 0;

    /* convert the int to string */
    snprintf(res, len + 1, "%i", x);

    /* return the result */
    return res;
}

int main()
{
    int x = 5;
    char *str = stringify(x);
    printf("%s\n", str);
    /* we free the memory allocated by malloc */
    free(str);
}
```

this would be one way you could to this in C. If you want to know more about the functions I used, have a look at:

- http://www.manpagez.com/man/3/vsnprintf/
- http://www.manpagez.com/man/3/malloc/

Answer (score 0):

`#define` statements are handled by the pre-processor before the compiler gets to see the code so it's basically a text substitution (it's actually a little more intelligent with the use of parameters and such).

Since `stringify(s)` is `#defined`, the preprocessor faithfully does it job.

`stringify(MAX_VALUE)` decays to `stringify(65536)` since MAX_VALUE is #defined to `65536`, also known at preprocessing.

But `Enumerations` are part of the C language itself and not known at preprocessing,
So, `stringify(MIN_VALUE)` retains as stringify(MIN_VALUE) and hence `toString(MIN_VALUE)`

To do integer arithmetic or to print

```
num = 65536
```

"yes", there is a way to make the preprocessor perform integer arithmetic, which is to use it in a `preprocessor` condition.

```
#if 1024*64 == 65536
    printf("num=65536\n");
#endif
```